# android drag and drop gridview ordering

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I created a drag and drop gridview (using an `OnDragListener`). Grid items can be dropped upon one another. However, I also want to be able to re-order them. I implemented this, but there is a major issue left standing: the user control part.

When I drag around my shadow object I want the items to make space for my dragged object while I am dragging it around. I already implemented the moving of the other items, but I cannot seem to figure out a way to find out IF/WHEN I am in between two items. I get drag events when I hoover ABOVE an item, but not in between then. The gridview does not get any `onTouchEvent` calls when I am dragging, not even `onInterceptTouchEvent` calls.

Does anyone know a way in which I can implement this?

I already tried:

1. Implementing `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the gridview. Problem: 
   The gridview does not get any `onTouchEvent` calls when I am dragging an item, not even `onInterceptTouchEvent` calls.
2. Setting another `draglistener` on the whole gridview. Problem: `ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION` gets only called a few times, not on every move (location change), as is documented (!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the padding between the grid items and gave the items themselfes some extra size, so that you are never inbetween items, but also on the side of one of the items. I detect when I'm at the side of an item and move the items accordingly to make space for my dragged item.